# Cancel sequence of ajax calls when one fails

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

In my store a have queue containing pending network requests.
When the action `ATTEMPT_FLUSH` is emmited, I want to *sequentially* send the requests. 
However if one of them fails and emits `ATTEMPT_FLUSH_CANCELLED`, the next ones should not be attempted (until I try again in the next `ATTEMPT_FLUSH`, of course).

Here's what I have so far

```
export const attemptFlushEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(ATTEMPT_FLUSH)
    .mergeMap(() => Observable.from(store.getState().queue)) // state.queue is an array
    .concatMap(action =>
        Observable.ajax(action.url)
        .map(response => removeFromQueue(action))
        .catch(err => Observable.of(attemptFlushCancelled())));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving up the actual ajax call should cancel the subsequent ajax on failure.

```
export const attemptFlushEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(ATTEMPT_FLUSH)
    .mergeMap(() => Observable.from(store.getState().queue)
      .concatMap(action => Observable.ajax(action.url)
        .map(response => removeFromQueue(action)))
      .catch(err => Observable.of(attemptFlushCancelled())))
    );
```